# Check if a video is able to play in an iframe

Tags: javascript, html, youtube

I have an iframe element which runs a video slideshow.
I need to check if the video is able to play. In case it is not i have to make show a validation message.

I do use this

```
`$.getJSON('https://noembed.com/embed',
                { format: 'json', url: someURL }, function (data) {
                    if (data.error) {
                        self._validationMessage.show(); //show the valiadtion message  from html
                    }
                });`
```

but the problem is some of the videos contain errors which are not prevent the video from running where other do.

I did also try to select the body of the iframe element, because when the video is not able to run the page is blank and as a result the body is empty, but is not possible to select it.

I cannot use youtube API since it requires personal API key.

Those are the Json files for each error

The first one -- Expected the data.error returns  error: "401 Unauthorized ↵"

```
 {"error":"401 Unauthorized \n","url":"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_pfSezsmsuw"}
```

The second one doesnt contain any error but the data.error returns error: "no matching providers found ↵"

```
{"thumbnail_url":"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/LhqLn1wKJAw/hqdefault.jpg","width":480,"height":270,"provider_url":"https://www.youtube.com/","author_name":"Largest Dams","title":"The Largest Aircraft Carrier in The World (full video)","version":"1.0","thumbnail_height":360,"type":"video","thumbnail_width":480,"provider_name":"YouTube","author_url":"https://www.youtube.com/user/itsd3000","url":"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LhqLn1wKJAw","html":"\n<iframe width=\" 480\" height=\"270\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/LhqLn1wKJAw?feature=oembed\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen=\"allowfullscreen\"></iframe>\n"}
```

Comment: U need to provide more details, more code examples.

Comment: What are some of the errors you are experiencing?

Comment: Hi, in the first case i am getting error: "401 Unauthorized ↵" which i believe is fine as the video cannot play in youtube as well and my validation message apears correctly. In the second case i am getting error: "no matching providers found ↵". This error doesnt prevent the video from running but it makes my validation message appears as it pass the if(data.error) { show validationMessage}

Answer (score 0):

When I tired to watch the YouTube video just using the link, it says the video is unavailable. Think this is the problem. Try it with another YouTube video and see if that works.

Comment: Did you try this http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LhqLn1wKJAw? In case you talk about the first one that is the expected the video is not playing. The problem is the second video. It is able to play but the data.error returns error: "no matching providers found ↵" and as a result make my validation message appear. I am trying to find a way to make the validation message appear only when the video is not able to play